# Copy page numbers from a pdf with a shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pdf-reader, bibliography

I read a lot of PDF files and take notes from them. I often like to include page numbers in these notes so that a reader can find what I am talking about. But this is a pain with a lot of typing.

Is there a way of quickly copying the page number from a pdf I am looking at,preferrably with a key bind.

## Bonus question

- Could I generate a reference to the page in the document with a single key?

## Approaches tried

I thought something like [zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) might do what I want but it does not. Perhaps there is something similarly "linuxy"

Comment: I do this with both Adobe Acrobat (to add boxes with notes) and One Note to add the PDF and add notes outside the PDF.  Depending on the PDF creation, I can copy page numbers to the One Note.

Comment: @John Interesting is there a shortcut for copy the page:D

Comment: If the PDF was created from a document (Word, Excel) then you should be able to highlight and copy. There is not, so far as I know, a special shortcut just for page numbers.